# How should matrix-based Parallax Scrolling work?

Tags: 2d, libgdx, matrix, parallax-scrolling

The question is at the end, as it requires a bit of context.

I'm not sure if my understanding, my code, or LibGDX's `ParallaxCamera` is wrong.

LibGDX's `ParallaxCamera` uses `Matrix4`s to achieve a parallax effect by transforming the vertices used in a `SpriteBatch#draw` call.

Depth is modelled as a float between 1 and 0. 1 means move directly proportionally to the camera; 0 means never move; 0.5 would move half as fast as the foreground.

Suppose I have a screen of 320x240. My camera is pointing at 160,120. **What should be the screen coords** for the following things?

```
World Coords    Depth    Screen Coords?
0,0             0,0      0,0

160,0           0.5,0    160,0
320,0           0.5,0    240,0

160,0           0.75,0   160,0
320,0           0.75,0   ???,0

160,0           1,0      160,0
```

I was expecting that if the camera is at X:160, then all things with world coords with X:160 should be drawn at screen coords with X:160. My thinking is that effectively that means everything should be 'lined up', and that moving the camera should give the impression of them all moving away from that point at different rates.

As it stands, my code is drawing something with X:160 and xDepth:0.5 at screenX:240. I don't think that's right, but I don't know if I'm misunderstanding what should happen, my code is wrong, or if the camera is wrong :(